# Matlab/Simulink - how to get value of variables set by the model arguments in a reference model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Suppose I have a Simulink model with 2 instances of the same reference model with model arguments that looks like this:

```
parent_model(model workspace: 'VarA = 1', 'VarB = 2')
  |___ model_refA (model argument: 'Var'
  |                model argument value: 'VarA')
  |
  |___ model_refA (model argument: 'Var'
                   model argument value: 'VarB')
```

Is there a way to query an instance of the model reference to obtain the correct value for 'Var' after it has been resolved by the model argument value?

Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: I would like more explanation in order to help you!

Comment: Hopefully this explains it better. Inside model_refA, there is a variable called 'Var'. This variable is set as a model argument. Inside parent_model, it has 2 instances of model_refA. In each instance, it sets its model argument 'Var' to different values. How do I get the value of 'Var' for a particular instance of the model reference? Something like: `mw=get_param('model_refA','modelWorkspace'); mw.evalin('Var')` but for a particular model reference instance.